# Given three sides of an isosceles trapezoid, find the smaller base side

Tags: trigonometry, geometry

I've been surprised at how challenging this problem is. Given an isosceles trapezoid, with the larger base b, the four angles, and the two equal sides c know, find the length of the shorter base a. Is the calculation even possible without knowing the height?

Comment: Clearly not; it depends on the angle the two equal sides make with the base. If the angle is close to zero, the remaining side is close to $b-2c$; if the angle is close to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, then remaining side is close to $b$.

Comment: what if the angles are known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Trapezium]$$a = b - 2 \,c \cos \alpha $$

where  $ \alpha = $ angle between the big side and one of equal sides length $c$.

Answer (score 0):

The height can be between $0$ and $c$, and the side $a$ can be any value between $b-2c$ and $b$.

Comment: So all that can be found are bounds? There's no definitive formula for base a? I find that surprising. After all, we know four angles and three sides of the geometry. That seems like a lot of information.

Comment: Isoceles means the angles are the same, not what their value is.

Comment: i edited the question so that the angles are know. if the angles are know, then is there some formula for a?